# Multiple Dex Files error due to multiple libraries installed

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I'm a total newbie when it comes to programming. I've been struggling trying to set up AdMob ads on this app... first trying with the old AdMob library, then multiple attempts to create AdMob ads now with the new Google Play Services library.

I'm getting this error:

```
[2014-05-22 14:00:10 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
[2014-05-22 14:00:10 - TheCevicheApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
```

...because I think I have the same googleplay library installed (at least) twice. I'm not sure (if this is the problem) which one to delete, and the proper way to delete the extra one.

I not allowed to post images yet, but here's a link to an image of my Eclipse Project Explorer that shows what libraries are installed and where:
http://tinypic.com/r/igb8k1/8

Comment: delete all duplicated google-play-services jars and leave the latest one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please excuse my ignorance, but 1) how do I tell which one is the latest, and 2) which folder should I delete the jars from?

Comment: Maybe just delete all of them and then add google play services again. Final result should be that there is only one google play services.